# What does "JVM processes" mean?

Tags: java, process

From Java In a Nutshell

> `jps`  provides a list of all active **JVM processes** on the local machine (or a remote machine, if a suitable instance of  `jstatd`  is running on the remote side).

What does "JVM processes" here mean,

- processes of the underlying OS which run JVM exactly, or
- processes that are supported by Java via `Process`, `ProcessBuilder` and `Runtime.exec()`...

Thanks.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jps.html

Comment: It means the first one of your two bullet points.

Answer (score 4):

A running Java Virtual Machine (JVM) instance is materialized by a native process launched by an OS while a `Process` class instance is a native process launched by a running JVM.
As each Java Virtual Machine is associated to a specific native process, instead of saying a process that runs a JVM, we could so shortcut it by a JVM process.

Comment: Thanks. What do "JVM processes" mean here?

Answer (score 0):

**JVM** stands for **J**ava **V**irtual **M**achine.

In plain English, a virtual machine (VM) is any piece of software that simulates a real machine. There are two kinds of VMs:

- system VM
- process VM

A system virtual machine provides the functionality of a real computer. A process virtual machines allows to execute programs in one specific programming language. The advantage of a process VM (sometimes also called *managed runtime environment*) is that it provides the same environment across different platforms.

**JVM is the process virtual machine for Java.**

Since of the main design goals of Java is portability, the Java language code gets compiled to an intermediate representation called *Java bytecode* that can be executed on a JVM.

So, basically **every time you run Java code you start an own JVM process**.

[image: Java bytecode on a Java Virtual Machine]

Image source: [Introduction to Computer Science using Java](https://chortle.ccsu.edu/java5/notes/chap05/ch05_4.html)

There are exceptions to that, namely special-purpose processors that can interpret Java bytecode: with such processors Java is executed directly on the hardware without using a virtual machine. An example are ARM processors endowed with the Jazelle DBX direct bytecode execution.